# ¿cómo filtrar en una BD datos repetidos en más de un campo?

Tags: sql, sql-server, mysqli

Tengo una tabla con los siguientes datos por ejemplo:

[image: Base de datos]

necesito filtrar y traer solo los registros que tengan repetidos el campo A, el B y el C
o sea en este caso la consulta que estoy buscando debería traer el Registro 1, 2, 5

Answer (score 0):

No se si es lo que quieres, pero la respuesta es bastante simple, igualando los campos

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLA
WHERE A = B AND B = C
```

Comment: Hola Roger gracias por responder, quizás me expliqué mal pero en mi BD tengo multiples registros, lo que busco con mi consulta es que todos estas líneas o registros sean devueltas para los que cumplan la condicion que tanto la columna A esté repetida, como tambien la B y la C (cada una repetida pero por separado).

Answer (score 0):

Una solución, para tener en cuenta los duplicados, es utilizar group by con count y después en el having restringir a que los resultados que sean mayores que 1.

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE (REGISTRO INT, A INT, B INT, C VARCHAR(3), D VARCHAR(4))
INSERT INTO @TABLE (REGISTRO, A, B, C, D)
VALUES
(1,1,123,'abc','a1b1'),
(2,1,123,'abc','a2b2'),
(3,1,123,'def','d3e3'),
(4,1,123,'ghi','g4h4'),
(5,1,123,'abc','a5b5'),
(6,1,456,'abc','a6b6');

;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS VECES
            , T.A
            , T.B
            , T.C 
    FROM 
          @TABLE T 
    GROUP BY T.A, T.B, T.C
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
SELECT T.* FROM @TABLE T
    INNER JOIN CTE ON T.A = CTE.A 
                    AND T.B = CTE.B 
                    AND T.C = CTE.C
```

Ahora la salida es las 3 filas completas.

[image: Salida]